# complementary slicing in a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

If I have a numpy array for example :

```
A = np.array([[3, 2], [2, -1], [2, 3], [5, 6], [7,-1] , [8, 9]])
```

I would like to separate the part of the array with the subarrays having -1 from the ones who don't.
Keep in mind that I'm working on very big data set, so every operation can be very long so I try to have the most effective way memory and CPU-time wise.

What I am doing for the moment is :

```
 slicing1 = np.where(A[:, 1] == -1)
 with_ones = A[slicing1]
 slicing2 = np.setdiff1d(np.arange(A.shape[0]), slicing1, assume_unique=True)
 without_ones = A[slicing2]
```

Is there a way to not create the `slicing2` list to decrease the memory consumption as it can be very big?
Is there a better way to approach the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way is to store the logical index needed and then in the second case index using its logical negation:

```
In [46]: indx = A[:, 1] != -1

In [47]: A[indx]
Out[47]: 
array([[3, 2],
       [2, 3],
       [5, 6],
       [8, 9]])

In [48]: A[~indx]
Out[48]: 
array([[ 2, -1],
       [ 7, -1]])
```

Comment: This is certainly better than using `setdiff1d` for many reasons. And since boolean arrays only use a byte per item, even two copies of a boolean index array will be smaller than an integer index array and its complement. To save even a bit more memory, I believe this won't make a copy: `numpy.logical_not(ix, out=ix)`.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to create without_ones with:

```
filter(lambda x: x[1] != -1,A)
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use a generator function:

```
A = np.array([[3, 2], [2, -1], [2, 3], [5, 6], [7,-1] , [8, 9]])

def filt(arr):
    for item in arr:
        if item[1]!=-1:
            yield item

new_len = 0
for item in A:
    if item[1] != -1:
        new_len += 1

without_ones = np.empty([new_len, 2], dtype=int)
for i, item in enumerate(filt(A)): 
    without_ones[i] = item
```