# Most concise way to get complementary slice in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, slice

What is the most concise (compact) way to give the complement of a `numpy.array` slice? Contrary to a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29112408/complementary-slicing-in-a-numpy-array) I have no speed consideration but ease of use/readability/generality in mind.

As an example, take the array `A=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])`. I am looking for the complement of `A[start:stop]`, e.g., for the complement of `A[2:4]` which would be `"comp of A[2:4]"=array([1,2,3,6])`. I am looking for a solution that works regardless of the content type. So A could contain also arrays, str and ideally in principle be of any dimension for which the normal [start:stop] slice operation works too.

Without claiming generality, this is what I currently use:

```
def comp(A,start,stop):
    if A.ndim == 1:
        out = np.hstack((A[0:start],A[stop:]))
    else:
        out = np.vstack((A[0:start],A[stop:]))
    return out
```

Comment: aren't you looking at set difference: `np.array(list(set(A) - set(A[2:4])))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one concise way with [`np.r_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) to generate those indices and then indexing into the input array -

```
A[np.r_[:start,stop:len(A)]]
```

Answer (score 2):

The `r_` solution that `@Divakar` proposes is a concise one for `numpy`, but it won't generalize to other classes.

```
In [195]: np.r_[0:2,4:6]                                                                         
Out[195]: array([0, 1, 4, 5])
```

It generates a list of indices that you want to keep, essentially `concatenate` of `np.arange(0,2)` and `np.arange(4,6)`.  Indexing with the list is `advanced indexing`, which makes a copy.

You can't use such a list to index a Python `list` or `string`.  They can only index elements.  To use it on list:

```
[alist[i] for i in np.r_[0:2,4:6]]
```

But lists have a delete syntax  `alist[2:4]=[]`

Strings don't have that because they are immutable.

A more universal approach is to concatenate/join two slices

```
np.concatenate([arr[0:2], arr[4:6]])
alist[0:2] + alist[4:6]
astr[0:2] + astr[4:6]
np.concatenate([arr[:, 0:2], arr[:, 4:6]], axis=1)
```

Your `hstack/vstack` code can be rolled into one with

```
np.concatenate((A[0:start],A[stop:]),axis=0)
```

since you are joining the slices on the first dimension in both cases.

The complement of a 2d slice:

```
arr[2:4, 2:4]
```

can't be a 2d array.  Different numbers of elements are left in each row.